# Adding Data annotation for a value that is got from query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I need to add data annotation for the web api service in the {ID} mentioned in below url to accept a max length of 7, else I should throw a custom exception. I donot have any model class for the same to use maxlength attribute. Appreciate your help.

http://xyz.com/**{ID}**

Comment: route constraint is the way to go although why throw a custom exception, thats not very RESTful. Return an HTTP status code.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try to do is the following, assuming from the url you have in the question:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults,
            new { id = @"\d{4}" } //Constraint
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultError", // Route name
            "{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "ThrowError" }, // Parameter defaults,
            new { id = @"\d{5,}" } //Constraint
        );
```

and have a `ThrowError(int id)` method in your controller which throws the error you want or redirects to an errorpage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not include a handler in your WebAPI method?

```
public SomeModel Get(int id)
{
    if (id != null && id <= 7)
         return something();

    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.{BadRequest|Forbidden|SomethingElse});
}
```